# How do I choose a CPU and a GPU for a fair comparison?

Tags: performance, cuda

I need to make a persuasive argument that a good GPU would be valuable to someone who needs to do certain calculations and may be willing to write his/her own code to do those calculations. I have written CUDA code to do the calculations quickly with a GPU, and I want to compare its computation time to that of a version adapted to use only a CPU. The difficult part is to argue that I am making a reasonably fair comparison even though I am not comparing apples to apples.

If I do not have a way to claim that the CPU and GPU that I have chosen are of comparable quality in some meaningful sense, then it could be argued that I might as well have deliberately chosen a good GPU and a bad CPU. How can I choose the CPU and GPU so that the comparison seems reasonable? My best idea is to choose a CPU and GPU that cost about the same amount of money; is there a better way?

Comment: Your best best would be to show how the GPU's parallelism is more suited to your number crunching needs than a CPU

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a bullet proof comparison method. You could compare units with similar price and/or units that were released around the same time. The latter would be to show that the state of the art technology at a given time in both products sets the GPU ahead.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider three main costs:

- Cost of initial purchase
- Development cost for the application
- Ongoing cost in power consumption

You can sum these up to get a total cost for using each solution for some period of time, for instance one year.

Also, take into account that it is only worth paying for increased performance if the increase was actually needed. For instance, you may need to run some calculation every day. If you have a full day to run the calculations, it may not matter if they run in 5 minutes or an hour.