# right way to report CUDA speedup

Tags: cuda

I would like to compare the performance of a serial program running on a CPU and a CUDA program running on a GPU.  But I'm not sure how to compare the performance fairly.  For example, if I compare the performance of an old CPU with a new GPU, then I will have immense speedup.

Another question:  How can I compare my CUDA program with another CUDA program reported in a paper (both run on different GPUs and I cannot access the source code).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135406/how-do-i-choose-a-cpu-and-a-gpu-for-a-fair-comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fairness, you should include the data transfer times to get the data into and out of the GPU. It's not hard to write a blazing fast CUDA function. The real trick is in figuring out how to keep it fed, or how to hide the cost of data transfer by overlapping it with other necessary work. Unless your routine is 100% compute-bound, including data transfer in your units-of-work-done-per-unit-of-time is critical to understanding how your implementation would handle, say, a lot more units of work.

For cross-device comparisons, it might be useful to report units of work performed per unit of time per processor core.  The per processor core will help normalize large differences between, say, a 200 core and a 2000 core CUDA device.

If you're talking about your algorithm (not just output), it is useful to describe how you broke the problem down for parallel execution - your block/thread distribution, for example.

Make sure you are not measuring performance on a debug build, or running in a debugger. Debugging adds overhead.

Make sure that your work sample is large enough that it is significantly above the "noise floor". A test run that takes a few seconds to complete will be measuring more of your function and less of the ambient noise of the environment than a test run that completes in milliseconds.  You can always divide the units of work by the test execution time to arrive at a sexy "units per nanosecond" figure, but you don't actually measure it that way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions.  I found your recommendation on cross-device comparison very useful.  And I agree that including the data transfer time will more the comparison fairer.  However, I think this doesn't handle the issue of an old (slow) CPU vs a new (fast) GPU.  Should I use something like the CPU and GPU released year to make the comparison fairer?  Or are there any other properties that would make the valid comparison?

Comment: CPU model number, number of cores, and year of release is about all you can do. A properly implemented CUDA routine will often run circles around even the latest multi-core CPU. How old the CPU is for baseline comparisons doesn't invalidate the CUDA performance. In defense of the CPU, CUDA GPUs would have horrible performance for general machine operations. GPUs excel only when the code and the data have been specially prepared for massively parallel execution, and most machine tasks are not.

Comment: Actually, whether you include data transfers is dependent on the application. You may be developing a kernel for which the inputs and outputs are produced/needed by other surrounding kernels on running on the GPU. In that case it would be unfair to include data transfers in the timing. This is an important consideration to make!

Comment: To really do a fair comparison to another processor, you should compare programs that fully utilize each processor. In other words, your CPU code should use multiple cores on a CPU, and (at least) be compiled with a compiler that can generate SSE intrinsics. Likewise, your GPU code should not leave SMs idle. And no, you shouldn't compare an old CPU to a new GPU, or vice versa. If you are doing perf/$ comparisons, use the same class devices.  E.g. if you are running on an NVIDIA Tesla GPU, compare to a server-class CPU, not a consumer-class CPU.

Comment: @harrism Yes, your kernel could be only one step in a larger food chain, but if you're measuring the whole system running end to end on the CPU, it would be an unfair comparison to measure only one function execution in the GPU case, ignoring the additional overhead of data I/O required on the GPU that the CPU is not as burdened with. Ignoring the data I/O or ignoring end-to-end completion seems to be the default for new CUDA fans. Overstating real world performance is actually damaging CUDA's credibility.

Comment: Well now you are just using common sense. It's generally best to measure both the speedup of the component you optimize, as well as the overall speedup of your application due to the optimization. But whether PCI-e transfer is included in that is application dependent. If you are doing a graphics app, there may be no PCI-e transfer. Or, if you are running on a processor where the GPU and CPU are on the same die. These days more and more of an application is moving to the accelerator, "always time data transfers over PCI-e" is just not always the most fair approach.

Answer (score 0):

The speed of cuda program on different GPUs depends on many factors of the GPU like memory bandwidth, core clock speed, cores, number of threads/registers/shared memory available. so it is difficult to compare the performance in different GPUs

Comment: Thank you and agree but it is good if we can come up with something that would help in comparing them (even if it helps bitly little)